# histogram for black and white image (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm taking an image processing class and we need to use matlab. As an assignment, we need to create a function that compute a gray image histogram. My  code is able to handle 256 bin, but it encounter this error when i try for 128 bin:

```
Error using accumarray, First input SUBS and third input SZ must satisfy ALL(MAX(SUBS)<=SZ).
```

My code is the following:

```
function hist = imgrayhist(imggray,n) 
%read the image
i = imread(imggray);

%calculate bin threshold 
threshold = 256/n;

%Calculate which bin each pixel belongs to
im_level = floor( i(:) / threshold);

%tranform the matrix to a vector
j = im_level(:);

hist = accumarray(j+1,1,[n 1]);
end
```

I know it is an out of bound error, but I have no idea how to fix this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons it doesn't work:

1. You should `ceil` your threshold to have a round number

   ```
   threshold = ceil(128/n);
   ```
2. The values in `i` are integers, which means that the division will round itself before doing the `floor` operation. Therefore, you need to convert it to `double`:

   ```
   im_level = floor( double(i(:)) / threshold);
   ```